# How to build LineageOS for a device without official support?

Tags: custom-roms, lineageos, builds

I have a Mi 8 Lite (platina), for which there is no official LineageOS support. But LineageOS custom ROM for the device is available on XDA. On further research, I can see that vendor files, device tree and kernel source code is available for my device:

1. [Kernel Source](https://github.com/MiCode/Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource/tree/nitrogen-p-oss)
2. [Device Tree](https://github.com/nysascape/device_xiaomi_platina)
3. [Vendor Files](https://github.com/nysascape/vendor_xiaomi_platina)

How do I build a LineageOS ROM for my device without official support?

Comment: Hello daltonfury42. Sorry, but development related questions are off-topic here. Please visit [help/on-topic] to know the scope of our site. I don't know whether [So] takes up such questions. Since you've already put efforts into helping others, I suggest you consider XDA, Medium, or some other platform to share this category of information. :-)

Comment: @Firelord This is not related to development, or writing custom ROMs. These are steps to 'build' a ROM by downloading and compiling it's source code. But if you still think it's a development question, I will move it to stackoverflow.

Comment: Questions related to building apps or ROMs are not considered within the scope of this website, so you're free to take it wherever it pleases you.

Comment: @Firelord Can you help me move this to stackoverflow?

Comment: @daltonfury42 I asked a moderator on [SO] and he responded that it is too broad for their site. May be try their meta or chat room and see if this can be turned to fit into their site's scope?

Answer (score 7):

Firstly you need to setup the build environment. You should be running Ubuntu 18.04. LineageOS [build guide](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/kenzo/build) for a random device can be used as a reference. Reproducing the steps here:

Install the build packages:

```
sudo apt install bc bison build-essential ccache curl flex g++-multilib gcc-multilib git gnupg gperf imagemagick lib32ncurses5-dev lib32readline-dev lib32z1-dev liblz4-tool libncurses5-dev libsdl1.2-dev libssl-dev libwxgtk3.0-dev libxml2 libxml2-utils lzop pngcrush rsync schedtool squashfs-tools xsltproc zip zlib1g-dev adb fastboot
```

Create the directories:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
mkdir -p ~/android/lineage
```

Install the repo command:

```
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
```

Put the ~/bin directory in your path of execution by adding the following to your `~/.profile` if it's missing:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Then, run `source ~/.profile` to update your environment. After that, initialize the LineageOS source repository and start downloading:

```
cd ~/android/lineage
repo init -u https://github.com/LineageOS/android.git -b lineage-16.0
repo sync
```

Downloading LineageOS source will take some time. After that we will deviate from the official build guide. Create a local manifest file telling the repo tool where to pick up the kernel source, device tree and vendor files. The corresponding file for platina can be downloaded from [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/daltonfury42/c33fdfa7a44f261018a5d35dea7eb245/raw/5fc372ec0d36117fa3e7698d8de1952c1bac6b6a/platina.xml). If you are building for a different device, use this manifest file as a reference and edit it accordingly. Save the file as

```
.repo/local_manifests/platina.xml
```

Rerun repo tool to fetch them:

```
repo sync
```

Initialise your build environment:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
```

Enable caching to speed up the build:

```
export USE_CCACHE=1
```

You should add the above line to your `.bashrc` file. Then set the max cache size:

```
ccache -M 50G
```

Configure jack:

```
export ANDROID_JACK_VM_ARGS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xmx4G"
```

Edit `device/xiaomi/platina/BoardConfig.mk` and set the parameter `TARGET_KERNEL_CONFIG` to `platina_user_defconfig`:

[image]

`TARGET_KERNEL_SOURCE` points to the kernel code that is to be used during the build. `TARGET_KERNEL_CONFIG` specifies which configuration is to be used. By looking in `arch/arm64/configs/` in the kernel source, I set the value to `platina_user_defconfig`

Finally start the build:

```
lunch 16
mka bacon -j8
```

This should lake a few hours to complete. I usually leave it running overnight. Here is where things get challenging. It’s possible that the build can fail due to errors, in which case you will have to fix it. Once the build has completed, you will find the zip file, ready to flash:

[image]

Comment: Do you know which signature key will be used when building a LineageOS image this way?